# How does the main function actually behave when written as main||integer

Tags: c

## I have tested this program on gcc it's answer is 1. I could not find the reason how?

```
main()
{
int c = 5;
printf("%d", main||c);
}
```

Answer:it is showing on gcc compilers (Dev C++)

Comment: What were you expecting the output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a logical `OR` operation. It evaluates to 1 if at least one of `main` is not a `NULL` pointer or `c` is nonzero; otherwise, it yields 0. Since `main()` is an existing function, a pointer to it is not `NULL`, and also `5` is not zero, so this code will print `1`.

Comment: @Atiq "but can we use a function without parenthesis" - Yes, you can, it then means a pointer to that function. What do you mean by "segregate with variables"?

Answer (score 3):

When it appears on its own without parentheses, `main` is a [pointer to function](http://c-faq.com/decl/ptrfuncinit.html) (effectively, the address of `main()`).

Thus

```
main || c
```

is equivalent to

```
(main != NULL) || (c != 0)
```

which always evaluates to true (i.e. `1`).

Answer (score 0):

`main||c` is a logical `OR` which will test the function pointer of `main` which is non-NULL and `c` which has some non-zero value. Since both of them aren't `zero` or `NULL`, it will always print `1` as this is the output of logical `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile it with the `-Wall` option to gcc (to get almost all warnings, with `-Wextra` you'll get even more). With `gcc-4.8` I'm getting

```
% gcc-4.8 -Wall atiq.c -o atiq
atiq.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]
 main()
 ^
atiq.c: In function 'main':
atiq.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 printf("%d", main||c);
 ^
atiq.c:4:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
atiq.c:4:14: warning: the address of 'main' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
 printf("%d", main||c);
              ^
atiq.c:5:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

I think the warning are clear enough. And you see that `main` has always a non-null address, so `main||c` is always true.

And your code is missing a `#include <stdio.h>`